# start an activity in Asyn-task

Tags: android, android-activity, asynchronous

I'm trying to perform a simple login process in an android application using json and GET request 
I get the username and password from the main activity then I pass it to login class which is a subclass of Async to etablich the login action 
after that I wnanted to start a new Activity called Profile where I'm going to display some data but It dosn't work here is my code :

```
package com.example.socialnetcit;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class Login extends Activity {

    Tools tools = new Tools();
    EditText edtname;
    EditText edtpass;
    String name;
    String pass;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                edtname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                name = edtname.getText().toString();
                pass = edtpass.getText().toString();
                if (tools.isEmpty(edtname) || tools.isEmpty(edtpass))

                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Plz enter user name and password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    String url = "http://example.com/Andoid/login.php?"
                            + "name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass;
                    login log = new login();
                    log.execute(url);

                }

            }
        });

    }
////// Login class 

    class login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            Boolean login = false;
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // HttpClient
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array

            if (httpEntity != null) {
                try {
                    String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(entityResponse);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String tmp = tools.JsonVerify(jsonObj).toString();
                if (tmp.equals("true")) {
                    Log.d("Testy", "login successful");
                    login = true;
                }
            }
            return login;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result == true) {
                  Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Wrong password or username ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

it close the current activity( login) and back to the first one ( the mains one to choose betwen login/register )

here is the log data :

```
12-17 01:24:11.080: I/ActivityManager(1723): START u0 {cmp=com.example.socialnetcit/.Profile} from pid 6126
12-17 01:24:11.080: D/ActivityManager(1723): TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.example.socialnetcit activityName: com.example.socialnetcit.Profile  bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
12-17 01:24:11.080: D/ActivityManager(1723): Showing guidance for pkgName: com.example.socialnetcit
12-17 01:24:11.100: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): event === app_launch
12-17 01:24:11.100: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): hiding guidance
12-17 01:24:11.100: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): hardKeyboard = 1
12-17 01:24:11.100: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): controllerType === DualAction
12-17 01:24:11.100: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): appName: SocialNetCIT, currentPkg: com.example.socialnetcit, event: app_launch, controller: DualAction
12-17 01:24:11.100: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): appName: SocialNetCIT
12-17 01:24:11.110: D/GuidanceScreen(2000): no guidance for com.example.socialnetcit.
12-17 01:24:11.620: W/ActivityManager(1723): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4b0f4214 u0 com.example.socialnetcit/.Login t29}
12-17 01:24:30.820: D/dalvikvm(1970): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 761K, 30% free 2770K/3936K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
12-17 01:25:26.400: D/dalvikvm(2410): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 777K, 29% free 2809K/3936K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
12-17 01:25:30.930: D/dalvikvm(1970): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 765K, 31% free 2753K/3936K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
```

after executing :

```
 Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? does it crash? does it do nothing?

Comment: it closes the current activity( login) and back to the first one ( the mains one to choose betwen login/register )

Comment: there is no way it behaves as you described, based on code pasted.

Comment: That is the confusion that  my code is clear !!! but I get that issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It closes the Login activity because you called `finish()`:

```
if (result == true) {
   Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
   startActivity(i);
   finish();
}
```

Based on your comments, it sounds like you expect to see the Profile activity, but instead you're seeing the main activity.  You should look in Profile activity to see why it's finishing.

Comment: you are right I had an error in Profile activity . thank you :)